# The p:commandLink inside the p:datagrid's p:celleditor is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid

The p:commandLink or p:commandButton inside the p:datagrid's celleditor is not working, when i click the commandLink it redirects me to the same page. Inside the celleditor the commandLink cant find its listener, however when i take it outside the celleditor it works perfectly.

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
                    <p:dataTable id="project" var="car" value="#{editdeleteview.proj_rec}" rowKey="#{car.id}" selection="#{editdeleteview.selected_rec}" selectionMode="single"  editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    All Projects
                </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{editdeleteview.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{editdeleteview.onRowCancel}"  update=":form:msgs"/>

                <p:column headerText="ID">

                        <h:outputLabel value="#{car.id}" />


                </p:column> 
                <p:column headerText="Title">
                <p:commandLink ajax="false" action="#{editdeleteview.openObjects(car)}"   ><h:outputText value="#{car.title}" /></p:commandLink>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><p:commandLink ajax="false" action="#{editdeleteview.openObjects(car)}"   ><h:outputText value="#{car.title}" /></p:commandLink></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{car.title}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>                   
                <p:column headerText="Description">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.description}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{car.description}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Insertion Time">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.insertionTimestamp}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{car.insertionTimestamp}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Close Time">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.closeTimestamp}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{car.closeTimestamp}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>  



                <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width:50px">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Delete">
                    <p:commandButton id="downloadLink1" value="Delete" ajax="false" class="btn btn-danger" icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{editdeleteview.delete(car)}">  

                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>                   
            </p:dataTable>               

    </h:form>
```

The p:commandLink outside the celleditor under the column title is working perfectly but inside the celleditor the commandLink is not working, the listener in the bean is

```
public String openObjects(Project p)
{


    HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("project_id", p.getId());
    session.setAttribute("project_title", p.getTitle());
    //session.setAttribute("project_title", "Hamdan");
    System.out.println("EditView: "+session.getAttribute("project_title").toString());
    return "Objects.xhtml";

}
```

I have also tried this [commandLink in cellEditor doesn't trigger action/actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379815/commandlink-in-celleditor-doesnt-trigger-action-actionlistener/15808810) but that didnt worked for me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 'not working' is way to vague. One of your other questions is marked as a duplicate of somthing. That duplicate contains information on how to debug further. Please do.

Comment: @Kukeltje i have also tried them, i have mentioned the problem that commandlink inside the cellEditor under the column "title" is not calling its listener and just redirects on the same page without any error.

Comment: @Kukeltje the commandLink outside the cellEditor tag is working perfectly, but i want that the commandLink inside cellEditor to work.

Comment: Yes I know what you want, but you can debug a lot more. If you say it is redirecting, that can only be done by the server, so the button does invoke something. Or is it just staying on the same page and doing nothing? Or are things refreshed. Check network traffic (request and response), debug the faces servlet and more. All things you can do an should do yourself first. And post version info...

Comment: First of all you have an ajax="false" in your p:commandLink which creates a ajax-less navigation therefore refreshes your page. Check that out.

Comment: the same commandLink outside the edittable is working absolutely fine, Infact on commandLink click i want to save which row was selected and want to redirect to another page, but the problem is that openObjects(Project p) is not being called and when i hover mouse on the commandLink when rendered the browser gives url of the samepage and # concatenated at the end. @EniSinanaj

Answer (score 2):

just use this and it will work

```
<f:facet name="output">
                            <p:commandLink action="#{editdeleteview.openObjects(car)}"
                                process="@this" immediate="true">
                                <h:outputText value="#{car.title}" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                    target="#{editdeleteview.selected_rec}" value="#{car}" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
```

Comment: process="@this" fixed it. TY

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `immediate="true"` on your command link component.
Have a look at this explanation by @BalusC:

> [Trying to understand immediate="true" skipping inputs when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960718/trying-to-understand-immediate-true-skipping-inputs-when-it-shouldnt)

Comment: The commandButton outside the cellEditor works, so if this is the solution, it would be good to explain why in the context of a cellEditor it **is** needed and **not** right outside it.

Comment: I'm proposing it as a solution in case it works. Haven't tried it myself actually. But i think that resolves the issue because the request of a commandLink inside a cellEditor might be conditioned by the cellEditor's own events or requests I'm guessing. 
@Kukeltje Feel free to vote down if the answer doesn't comply with the rules. No hard feelings. :)

Comment: No, no downvote since I do not know if it helps or not. But if you have not tried, better to post short things like this as a comment next time and turn it into an answer if it helped. The `process="this"` referred to in the question solves or should solve what you describe

Answer (score 0):

I'm using primefaces 6.3-SNAPSHOT, this problem still exists, this is how I resolved it :

JSF :

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" action="#{editdeleteview.openObjects(car)}"   >     
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.title}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText onclick="stopEventPropagation(event)" value="#{car.title}" style="width:100%"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:commandLink>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function stopEventPropagation(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```